# MVVM knockout: check html binding

Tags: html, events, mvvm, knockout.js, data-binding

is there a way to check when html is set, e.g. here:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="drag-template">
    <div>
        <div class="htmlText" data-bind="html: text"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This is within a listView and I want to check width and height of this div (.htmltext) after the text has been binded/set.
thanks!

Comment: If you are using "template" binding to render this template, probably you can use "afterRender" callback (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove) to get required dimensions.

Comment: yes, but I'm using data-template="" syntax because the knockout template binding doesn't work for the kendo listView (which I use here).

Comment: Please provide the additional info and bootstrapping code for that as well, if it's important. If possible, try to change the code into a [mcve].